# Use of NOT EXISTS in PHP Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have worked with NOT EXIST in Oracle but my SQL query with NOT EXIST is not working on PHP/Mysqli

```
mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users u where u.active=1 AND u.allowed=1 NOT EXIST

(SELECT f.uid FROM featured2 f WHERE f.uid=u.id) ORDER BY RAND() ");
```

Actually, I want all results from table **users** except the results from table **featured2** Where **f.uid=u.id**

Comment: My personal preference would be to avoid a `NOT EXISTS (correlated_subquery)`, and to use an anti-join pattern (i.e. a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN to return all rows from users along with matching rows from `featured2`, and then an `IS NULL` predicate to filter out all the matching rows, returning only rows from `users` that didn't have a matching row in `featured2`.) If you use a `NOT IN (subquery)` instead, be careful that the subquery doesn't return a `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `NOT EXISTS` in MySQL, and you need an `AND` before it.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.active=1
AND u.allowed=1
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT f.uid FROM featured2 f WHERE f.uid=u.id
)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Oh My mistake, its NOT EXISTS in Oracle too but didnt notice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `NOT IN` insted `NOT EXIST`

Comment: @DellDilshod: I'd test them, that's not *necessarily* faster.

Comment: @DellDilshod Is there any difference between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @user3667167: Check this out: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/  `NOT IN` may actually be faster.